# PHPUnit-Netbeans class not found exception

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, netbeans-7.3

I integrated PHPUnit into netbeans and now want to generate tests for my code.

```
<?php

/**
     * Action User
     *
     * user api
     *
     * @link http://getfrapi.com
     * @author Frapi <frapi@getfrapi.com>
     * @link rsmobile/user/:id
     */
    class Action_User extends Frapi_Action implements Frapi_Action_Interface
    {

    }
?>
```

I tried to do that by right clicking and `selecting Tools->Create PHPUnit Tests`. But it gave this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Frapi_Action' not found in /Users/username/Documents/.../src/   
frapi/custom/Action/User.php on line 12
```

Then I added dummy `Frapi_Action` class in file User.php and then it generated skeleton class.

```
<?php

/**
     * Action User
     *
     * user api
     *
     * @link http://getfrapi.com
     * @author Frapi <frapi@getfrapi.com>
     * @link rsmobile/user/:id
     */

    class  Frapi_Action {} 

    class Action_User extends Frapi_Action implements Frapi_Action_Interface
    {

    }
?>
```

Why it gave that Class not found error? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding path of the file containing `Frapi_Action` class.

```
require_once 'path/of/file';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not in the source code in the original example.  You either need to include/require the external file containing the class (recommended) or have the class in this code.